IOPS Torn page detection algorithm 2005 docs how does it work
I was reading this where they are explaining torn page detection and I did not get it
Does anybody has any idea?

It doesn't: "This content has been retired and may not be updated in the future. The product, service, or technology mentioned in this content is no longer supported.".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/logging-data-storage-algorithms#torn-page-detection might be a better link. What is the question exactly, what are you having difficulty with?

I read that, and that is basically what it is. However, there are some checks on the page header and reverse checks that involve two steps and happen per 512 KB, so 16 times in total. The document explains how they check this, but I just did not understand it.

That doc does a pretty good job of explaining it:

Torn page protection toggles a two bit pattern between 01 and 10 every
time the page is written to disk. Write A obtains bit protection of 01
and write B obtains bit protection of 10. Then write C obtains 01 and
so on. The low order (last) two bits of each 512-byte sector are
stored in the page header and replaced with the torn bit pattern of 01
or 10.

The idea is to write a 2-bit field on each sector that alternates between 10,01,10,01... each time the page is written, and also store those bits on the page header.  When reading the page from disk, if all the sectors don't have the correct pattern, then the page was not written correctly, and SQL Server will raise an error.
But there's a complication. The sector isn't a logical part of the page, so the end of each 512-byte sector is going to be in the middle of a slot or some other page structure.  So there's no field to write to.  So the trick is to store the first two bits of each sector in the page header, and replace them with a the torn bits.
If the page passes torn page detection, the torn bits are replaced so the page can be read normally.

Thanks a lot for the clarification
